# Piper J3 Cub: external lighting setup and history?

Tags: aircraft-lighting

It's quite easy to find the external lighting setup (colors, location on the aircraft and frequency of navigation, anti-collision and landing lights) for big airliners online. I'm interested in the Piper Cub and have not been able to find much. Most videos on YouTube are shot in daylight or, if they were shot at night, tend to be of model airplanes.

From pictures I've found out:

- navigation lights are of course red and green and positioned on the front-most, outer-most points of the wings as would be expected
- (almost all) pictures show a red light atop the vertical stabilizer

What I've not been able to find out yet for sure *with regard to still flight-worthy* Piper Cubs:

- is there (always/usually/sometimes) a red light at the bottom?
- what's the red top and bottom (if any) lights' blinking frequency?
- if there are strobe lights, where are they positioned and what is their strobing pattern?
- are there Piper Cubs with landing lights or has the type always exclusively been VFR?

And in terms of history:

- seeing as the Piper Cub was first built in 1937, last in 1994, and there was a gap from '83 to '88 with no production, how did its lighting setup change during that time? Where there any electrified Cubs produced at all, or is any electrification, including lights, completely custom?

Comment: I don't think the original cubs had an electrical system...

Comment: thank you Ron, I changed the last paragraph accordingly

Comment: I don't think J-3 Cub was made until 1994—the PA-18 Super Cub was. Of interest is addition of electrical system on the later.